# In graphics::par(new = TRUE) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot

Tags: r, plot, graphics, par

I want to take off the warning:`calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot`

In my developing package, I intend users to draw curves over previously drawing curves for comparison. To do so, I put the code `graphics::par(new=T)` for every `plot()` in my package. However the following warning occurs:

```
Warning messages:
  In graphics::par(new = TRUE) : calling par(new=TRUE) with no plot
```

**How to delete this warning?**

Comment: Maybe `suppressWarnings(par(new=TRUE))`

Comment: Where should I put `suppressWarnings(par(new=TRUE))` ? I execute in global enviroment but warning occur.
`.

Comment: I changed from `graphics::par(new=T)` to `suppressWarnings( graphics::par(new=T))`. But warning occur.

Comment: Odd. I get the same warning without `supressWarnings` but get no warning when I use it. Not sure why you are getting a different result.

Comment: Thank you for your tring... I again try.

Comment: I am sorry, for simple code, warning is deleted. Thank you !!

Comment: A different solution could be to first test if there is a plot. Only set new to TRUE if there is a plot. `if(dev.cur() > 1) { par(new=T) }`

Comment: Thank you. I also wanted to know such  a detection of plots. I learn a lot from you. I also try it. very thank you for letting me know codes and your kind reply.